# Prove that the 1st coordinate of an eigenvector is nonzero (2x2 matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I just can't figure out how this works, so I hope you guys can help me out:

Given is a matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-a_1 & -a_2\end{bmatrix}$ with $a_i 
\in \Bbb{R}, a_2 \neq 0$.

Prove that for every eigenvector $s = \begin{bmatrix}s_1\\s_2\end{bmatrix}$ of $A$ it holds that $s_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: if $s_1=0$ then $As=\begin{bmatrix} s_2 \\ -a_2s_2 \end{bmatrix}\neq \lambda s$ for any $\lambda$ since if $s_1=0$ then $s_2\neq 0$ (or else $s$ is not an eigenvector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is shown that a 2 by 2 matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$$
is simply a linear transformation where the unit vector  $i=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is transformed to $i'=\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}$ and unit vector $j=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is transformed to $j'=\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}$. i' and j' are just notations.

Eigenvectors are then the vectors that are only scaled after the transformation is applied.

Let $A_1 = -a_1$ and $A_2 = -a_2$. 
So $i'=\begin{bmatrix}0\\A_1\end{bmatrix}$ and $j'=\begin{bmatrix}1\\A_2\end{bmatrix}$, but $A_2 \neq 0$. Now $i'$ is a vector parallel to the y-axis and $j'$ is just some other matrix that isn't parallel to the x-axis (or y-axis for that matter).

However, if the eigenvector has $s_1=0$, then it was a scalar multiple of $j$, but now $j'$ cannot be parallel to $j$ as it has the 1 there.

---

But this can be more easily solved by contradiction. An Eigenvector,$v$, is what is it when, $$(A-I\lambda)v = 0$$, and $v$ is non-zero

For the sake of contradiction, let $s_1=0$
Then, $$(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\A_1 & A_2\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\lambda\end{bmatrix})\begin{bmatrix}0\\s_2\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}0-\lambda & 1\\A_1 & A_2-\lambda\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\s_2\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}0(0-\lambda) & s_2(1)\\0(A_1) & s_2(A_2-\lambda)\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

Since $s_2(1) = 0$, $s_2 = 0$, but then $v$ is the zero matrix.

This contradicts the definition of an eigenvector, so $v$ does not exist when $s_1=0$, which thus proves that $s_1 \neq 0$